# Is it possible to make a UIView begin tracking touches AFTER the screen is touched? (e.g. menus)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

Say I'm a user and I long-press the screen to bring up a menu of options.

Without lifting my finger, how would I tell the new menu view that was just presented to start tracking the touches as the user moves their finger?

I basically want to say "Hey UIView, there's a finger moving above you, can you start tracking that?"

Answer (score 0):

You can resend touch position from your gesture recogniser by using custom methods, for example:

```
CGPoint locationInMenu = [recogniser locationInView:menu];
<....> 
[menu handleTouchBegin:locationInMenu];
<...>
[menu handleTouchMoved:locationInMenu];
<...>
[menu handleTouchEnded:locationInMenu];
```

Comment: It's presenting a new view controller as a popover for the menu, so the gesture recognizers aren't firing any longer. UIAlertController actually has similar functionality.

Comment: Why you can't replace popover to a custom view to display your menu?

Comment: I think, when you are presenting a view controller (or rotate device), it is cancelling touch chain, and you cant get touch.